# webapi2: execute authorization attribute filters with OR instead on AND

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, single-sign-on, asp.net-authorization

Here is my situation:
I have an API and I'm securing it with `SSO`. What I want is that based in the `JWT` issuer, I apply one attribute or another, so is it possible to put both authorization attributes to my controller and execute the request if at least one authorization attribute decides that the token is valid and I have a desired claim inside?

I don't want to put all this login inside one attribute, due to SRP.

Thanks

Comment: Filter attributes are restrictive by default, as soon as any one filter attribute "fails" the request pipeline stops and subsequent filter attributes are not tested. If you wanted to change that logic and then only for specific filter combinations you would have to rewrite/extend that pipeline (it is possible but I would not recommend it). See [Aspnet Web Api Poster](https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf) for detail on where this is done. (*I do not know which type you need to extend to make this happen*)

Comment: Can you tell me the class name of the pipeline I would need to extend/decorate?

Comment: Could you just write one extended filter attribute that runs validation based on the required conditions? Basically combine the two into one?

Comment: This is not a good practice, due to single responsibility principle. And if in the future I will have multiple token issuers, I would need to change existing code, and break open-closed principle... These are the reasons for why I would like to avoid this approach.

Comment: Are you using the OWIN libraries? i.e. app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication